# Spring data MongoDb custom query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project in spring boot and using mongoDb for database.

Now how do make this query work

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
```

How do I convert into custom query using @Query annotation in spring data mongodb?

Comment: @Query annotation supports regular find queries not aggregate queries.

Comment: @Veeram any idea for this then -  db.person.find().limit(1).skip(10)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom repo to achieve the same using mongoTemplate.

```
    SampleOperation sample = Aggregation.sample(1);
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(sample);
        AggregationResults<T> result =
            this.mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "CollectionToSearch","Return-type-object");
    return result.getMappedResults();
```